# iOS 11 UIActivityViewController crashes printing PDF

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a simple invocation of a `UIActivityViewController` in my viewController which passes in a `String`, a `UIImage` and a PDF (as `Data`). The code worked fine in iOS 10, and continues to work fine with all functions (e.g. Copy, Mail, Markup as PDF) *other than* Print which crashes with nothing on the console. If I comment out the PDF representation, the Print function works perfectly well with the `UIImage`. The PDF is well formed, and displays as expected in Mark up PDF and AirDrop.

Does anyone have any insights into what has changed?

**Update**

No change in Xcode 9b5, iOS 11b5.

```
override func action(button: UIBarButtonItem) {
    guard let layer = self.currentLayer, let cgImage = layer.thumbnail else { return }
    var representations: [Any] = [
        UIImage(cgImage: cgImage),
        layer.collection.svg, // String representation
        ]

    if let pdf = layer.pdfDataDefault() { // Data
        representations.append(pdf)
    }

    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: representations, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = button
    self.present(activityVC, animated: true) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Call stack at the crash (which is "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x58)") shown below. Nothing shown on console.

[image]

Crash log :

Date/Time:       2017-08-06 12:34:50 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 11.0 (Build 15A5327g)
Architecture:    arm64
Report Version:  26

Data Source:     KPerf Lightweight PET
Kernel Cache:    0xffffffe000000000 7520411B-BFF1-86C3-E564-A279565AC465
Reason:          Fence-hang-com.apple.DocumentManager.Service: 627ms handling fence, blown-fence (fence duration=629ms)

Command:         com.apple.DocumentManager.Service
Path:            /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DocumentManagerUICore.framework/PlugIns/com.apple.DocumentManager.Service.appex/com.apple.DocumentManager.Service
Identifier:      com.apple.DocumentManagerUICore.Service
Version:         1.0 (1)
Parent:          launchd [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bl8O2.png)
PID:             1054

Duration:        0.60s
Steps:           12 (50ms sampling interval)

Hardware model:  J98aAP
Active cpus:     2

Comment: You are testing it on iPad or on iPhone ?

Comment: Testing on an iPad Pro. Also crashes in simulator.

Comment: @Grimxn would you mind attaching the crash log for better understanding of this issue ?

Comment: @Shreekara have added crash log & call stack.

Comment: Do you need the comma you have here: layer.collection.svg, // String representation?

Comment: @CodeBender - no, the comma is not needed after the last element of an array, but neither is it wrong. I use it when writing arrays that I may add to later or re-order so that I can just paste and cut the lines.

Comment: Can it be a permission issue? I have a similar problem trying to export JPG to Photos. Worked on iOS < 11, but not on iOS11. Then I tried sharing JPG by email - works, so the only case in which it crashes is when it tries to access Photos Library.

Comment: Maybe you should add something to info.plist (trying to use Bluetooth?). My problem was solved by this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527321/photo-capture-permission-problems-in-ios-11

Comment: @Alexey - thanks, I will try that.